# Adding an array of seconds to a reference datetime

Tags: python, datetime

How do I add an array of seconds to a reference datetime in python e.g:

```
ref_time = datetime.datetime(year=2017, month=6, day=5, hour=10, minute=30, second=30)

secs = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

The result needs to be something:

2017,6,5,10,30,30

2017,6,5,10,30,31

2017,6,5,10,30,32

2017,6,5,10,30,33 
   etc etc

I have tried this but its not working, what am I doing wrong?

```
d = datetime.timedelta(seconds=np.int(secs))
new_timestamp = timestamp+d
```

Sorry for the simple question, i'm quite new to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timedelta` accepts one argument as the second, that means you need to pass the seconds within the `secs` tuple one at a time. You can achieve this simply using a list comprehension:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: ref_time = datetime.datetime(year=2017, month=6, day=5, hour=10, minute=30, second=30)

In [3]: secs = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

In [4]: [ref_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=i) for i in secs]
Out[4]: 
[datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 10, 30, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 10, 30, 31),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 10, 30, 32),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 10, 30, 33),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 10, 30, 34),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 10, 30, 35),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 10, 30, 36),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 10, 30, 37),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 10, 30, 38),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 10, 30, 39),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 5, 10, 30, 40)]
```